# Почему PHP все время перезаписывает строку в файле JSON?

Tags: php, json

Я пытаюсь добавить `user` в `json`, но каждый раз он перезаписывает строку, и выходит что там один `user`. Я правильно описал что каждая строка делает? Но почему он перезаписывается?

```
$input = json_decode($_POST["phones"], true);
//вот что в `input`-е если что.
//$input = '[["5345", "345345", "123"], "Michael", "Podlevskykh"]';

$file = file_get_contents('jsn.json'); //получаем файл
$output = json_decode($file,TRUE);//декодируем
unset($file); // чистим переменную

// потом добавим в JSON
$output = [    
    'user2' => [
        'first_name' => $input[1],
        'last_name' => $input[2],
        'phones' => [
            'phone_1' => $input[0][0],
            'phone_2' => $input[0][1],
            'phone_3' => $input[0][2]
        ]
    ]
];        

file_put_contents('jsn.json',json_encode($output));//преобразуем в строку          
unset($output); //чистим
```

Comment: `$output =` это явно замена, а не добавление

Comment: 6 строка? @andreymal Что подскажите?

Comment: Используйте array_merge или его рекурсивного собрата вместо присвоения output

Comment: Спасибо, я уже решил проблему. Через `mege` я пробовал, но он сливает два в один, а мне надо `[ name, last,  [phones...]  ]` @DanielProtopopov

Answer (score 2):

Вы перезаписываете исходный массив. Добавлять надо с помощью оператора `[]`:

```
$output[] = [    
    'user2' => [
        'first_name' => $input[1],
        'last_name' => $input[2],
        'phones' => [
            'phone_1' => $input[0][0],
            'phone_2' => $input[0][1],
            'phone_3' => $input[0][2]
        ]
    ]
];
```